# How to restrict a subclass from overriding/implementing a superclass method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract class with abstract method method1 and method2. I have classes A,B and C that extend abstract class.

My question is how do I restrict class B only from overriding method2? I want all other classes to be able to override any method by will.

If this is not possible using abstract classes, is it possible to implement such a case using interface? If so, could you please explain me with an example?

Here is one such case I want to implement. Abstract class bird has abstract method fly(). I want eagle to be able to override it but not the class penguin

```
    abstract class bird{
            abstract void fly();
    }
    class eagle extends bird{
            @override
            void fly(){
                    Sysout("I can fly really high!");
    }

    class penguin extends bird{
            @override
            /*How do I make sure this method is not at overridden, because there are chances that      this method could be accidentally overridden*/
            void fly(){
                    Sysout("I cannot fly");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use System.out.println in abstract method. lol..

Comment: I dont think Fly() should be a member of bird, if clearly there are some birds that cant fly ;)

Comment: this is what turns me off about SF. Free will over spreading garbage. @OP: are you sure your bird class is correct? and what about eagle? Please read about Java language fundamentals. A few hours spent reading will save you a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: an quick edit wont solve your problem dude. are you sure an abstract method can have a body?

Comment: stratagey design pattern should be applied to meet your requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a class in the middle of `B` and the super class that overrides `method2` and marks it as `final`. Then, `B` will extend from this middle class and won't be able to override `method2`.

Note that in this case, it would be better to add behavior by using interfaces rather than extending methods. So, for example:

```
public interface CanFly {
    void fly();
}

public class Eagle implements CanFly {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        //...
    }
}

public class Penguin {
    //I cannot fly, I do not need to implement CanFly
}
```

Comment: So if classes A and C want to override method2, do they need to extend from the abstract class where method2 is not final?

Comment: the OPs question was not about this. he was just asking 'how to prevent overriding in subclass' and you explained about interface based behavior injection.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza great answer. I would like to know the reason for using interfaces for this particular problem. why this approach is superiour to final-method in class approach.

Comment: @Nazgul read the first sentence of my answer, which covers OP's problem. After that, I propose an alternative solution to the design.

Comment: @maxx777 because not all birds know how to fly, and they must not know either. That belongs to each class that extends bird. When you want specific behavior for your classes you usually use interfaces and implement them. But if your design starts to get horrible, you stop using interface implementation and go for composition and use strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can't..you can either allow every subclass or no one.
Just make an interface for the method you don't want to be implemented by B and make so that A and C implement this interface, while B just extends the abstact class.